# HttpSelfHost Serializar entidades filhas + session nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, nhibernate

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
    // GET: api/Pedido/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Orcamento))]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        using (OrcamentoRepository or = new OrcamentoRepository())
        {
            var orcamento = or.PesquisarPedidoAbertoPorNumeroComanda(null, id);
            //var teste = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(orcamento, Parametros.JsonConfig.JsonSerializerSettings);

            return Ok(orcamento);
        }
    }
```

e a seguinte configuração:

```
    public static JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented, 
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, 
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All, 
        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver()
        {
            IgnoreSerializableAttribute = true 
        }
    };
```

A chamada normal para esse método não retorna o objeto, pois a session fecha no return antes mesmo de serializar o objeto...

Mas se eu removo o comentário na linha JsonConvert.SerializeObject(), simplismente faço a serialização para uma variavel teste que nao vai ser usada, o método acaba retornando normalmente. (nesse momento ele carrega as listas filhas que estão configuradas como LazyLoad no nhibernate)

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma configuração que posso alterar para ele fechar a session do using apenas depois de serializar e enviar, ou vou ter que fazer a conversão manualmente e enviar o json em formato string.

Implementei o padrão repository na ApiController, está funcional porém não sei se é correto fazer isso

```
public class ApiControllerRepository<R> : ApiController
{
    protected R Repositorio;

    public ApiControllerRepository()
    {
        Repositorio = Activator.CreateInstance<R>();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        ((IDisposable)Repositorio).Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas em que momento a session tá sendo fechada? É no método `Dispose` do repositório?

Comment: Sim, o repositório implementa IDisposable justamente pra nao ficar session aberta. Só que a controller esta fechando antes de gerar a resposta

Comment: Ou pra web eu deveria deixar a session sempre aberta? ai seria uma session por controller, acredito que desperdiçaria muita memória

Comment: É que tá meio mal planejado. O pipeline em si não vai acabar no retorno do controller. Ou você vai ter que alterar o momento de fechar a session, ou vai precisar fazer eager load das entidades que quer retornar. Não vejo saída fora disso.

Comment: Estou começando com web, não entendo muito, poderia explicar melhor porque não acaba no retorno?

Comment: por acaso o método `PesquisarPedidoAbertoPorNumeroComanda()` não é assíncrono, é?